# CSV export giving #<Product:0xba4618> and similar entries instead of real data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am following this http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel and it looks to be pretty straight forward. I have included 'csv' and have put the code in controller index file and in model.

Now when I am clicking on /products.csv, it do export the list of products in csv but instead of having actual data it is having entries like **#**, what am I doing wrong ?

EDIT - here is the product.rb

```
  attr_accessible :name, :size, :email

  def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |product|
        csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: can you please share your `product.rb` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your products controller define a method as below:

def export_csv

```
    @Products = Product.find(:all)
    csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
        # header row
        csv << ["product_name","product_type"]
        # data row
        @products.each do |t|
            csv << [t.product_name, t.product_type]
        end
    end
    send_data(csv, :type => 'text/csv')
end
```

In your routes:
match 'csv' => 'products#export_csv', :as => :csv
  In your view give a link for CSV:
 link_to "CSV", csv_path

Comment: Can you give me complete working code ? I am confused which code needs to be put in controller and which to be in model ?